# Create a Pattern Lock in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx-8

I would like to create a pattern lock for desktop application using javaFx and i am using java 11. is it possible to implement using SceneBuilder? if so please let me give some idea to build this application.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KstL4GwqYUA

Comment: No, that's not possible. SceneBuilder (at least the latest  version I used) does not allow you to create logic; It's only capable of designing a interface which may be done as part of designing the control, but the interaction logic needs to be implemented in java. Btw: "giving you some idea" is not concrete enough a question to be on topic here.